# How to link libavcodec, libavformat in automake?

Tags: c++, makefile, ffmpeg, automake, libtool

I am using the libavcodec and libavformat libraries from ffmpeg in a C++ project. Linking -lavcodec -lavformat with the g++ compiler works fine, but I'm not sure what goes wrong when I try to use the same code compiled in an automake project.

Working fine:

```
g++ -o test -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -lavcodec -lavformat test.cpp
```

Not working Makefile.am:

```
binaryname_LDFLAGS= -lavcodec -lavformat
```

Error:

```
....
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(nut.o):function 
ff_nut_add_sp: error: undefined reference to 'av_tree_node_size'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(nut.o):function 
ff_nut_add_sp: error: undefined reference to 'av_tree_insert'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(nut.o):function 
ff_nut_free_sp: error: undefined reference to 'av_tree_enumerate'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(nut.o):function 
ff_nut_free_sp: error: undefined reference to 'av_tree_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(rtp.o):function 
ff_rtp_get_payload_type: error: undefined reference to 'av_opt_get_int'
...
```

also not working:

```
LDFLAGS=...-lavcodec -lavformat
```

Error:

```
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:99: error: undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:101: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_find_decoder'
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:109: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_alloc_context'
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:120: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_open2'
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:125: error: undefined reference to 'av_init_packet'
src/dsp/audioDecoder.cpp:188: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_decode_audio3'
```

In the second case, if I don't set any linker, the include header cannot be found so the linker seems somehow recognized.

make V=1 returns:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Go to '/path/to/trunk'
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O2 -lrt -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS   -o binaryname progsrc/binaryname/binaryname-binaryname.o    -lm  -lpthread -ldl -lmygeneratedlibrary
libtool: link: g++ -O2 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -o binaryname progsrc/binaryname/binaryname-binaryname.o  -lm /path/to//trunk/.libs/lmygeneratedlibrary.a -lrt -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lpthread -ldl
make[1]: Leave '/path/to/trunk'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CPPFLAGS` is for the **C** **P**re-**P**rocessor. Not C++ flags. That's `CXXFLAGS`. For linker stuff, you want `LDFLAGS`.

Your Makefile.am doesn't seem to follow canonical Makefile.am format. You probably want it more like ([taken from here](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/)):

```
# what flags you want to pass to the C compiler & linker
CFLAGS = # C compiler flags
LDFLAGS = # Linker flags

# this lists the binaries to produce, the (non-PHONY, binary) targets in
# the previous manual Makefile
bin_PROGRAMS = targetbinary1 targetbinary2 [...] targetbinaryN
targetbinary1_SOURCES = targetbinary1.c myheader.h [...]
targetbinary2_SOURCES = targetbinary2.c
.
.
targetbinaryN_SOURCES = targetbinaryN.c
```

Also, make sure that when you include FFmpeg's headers, you surround them with `extern "C"`. For example:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
```

Comment: ok I first build a static library (that uses the source code including libavcodec) and then link it to a binary. I set now according to your answer in the Makefile.am the libraryname_LDFLAGS and the binaryname_LDFLAGS to -lavformat -lavcodec , but still get the error undefined reference. What am I missing here?

Comment: @user2212461: `-lavutil`. Also, post the COMPLETE output of `make V=1`.

Comment: adding -lavutil to the linkerflags did't remove the error notification. I added the output of make V=1 in my post.

Comment: and -lavutil, as stated at the very top of my question, was not necessary before I used automake

Comment: @user2212461: `-lavutil` is necessary. `libavformat` depends on it. You would have gotten errors about it missing if you didn't have these other errors first.

Comment: @user2212461: When you include your FFmpeg headers, are you surrounding them with `extern "C" { ... }`?